# Cassandra-Hadoop integration

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I'm interested in integrating Cassandra and Hadoop, more precisely, using Cassandra as input for Hadoop jobs. Each Cassandra node is also a Hadoop node.

I found these tutorials [1](http://greenstorming.blogspot.com/2012/03/integrating-cassandra-with-hadoop.html) and [2](http://gerrymcnicol.com/index.php/2014/01/21/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-7-modifying-your-mapreduce-code-to-read-and-write-from-cassandra/) that somewhat explain the integration. I'm new to Cassandra so I'm still figuring out some things.

My question is - do I always need to use the whole ColumnFamily (table) as input to MapReduce job, or is there way to specify which rows you want (at least by key)?

If the whole ColumnFamily is used, would the correct approach be to emit only the rows that satisfy some condition out of the Mapper? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [official doc](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive) about current state of cassandra and hadoop integration.

> do I always need to use the whole ColumnFamily (table) as input to MapReduce job, or is there way to specify which rows you want (at least by key)?

No, you can always specify rows using `CqlConfigHelper.setInputWhereClauses` option of `CqlPagingInputFormat`.